# How to fix component error in React "./src/components/App.js 'Layout', 'Home' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, react-bootstrap

I'm learning to work with React and I got this little mistake, and I still don't know how to fix it.

> Failed to compile ./src/components/App.js   Line 9:    'Layout' is not
>   defined  react/jsx-no-undef   Line 11:  'Home' is not defined
>   no-undef Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

I hope you can guide me, I was checking a tutorial on YouTube and I followed all the steps, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: You probably forgot to import the components; add something like this to the start of the script: `import Layout from "./Layout";` Same for `Home`.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: can you show code inside App.js file ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you show your code it's hard to find the problem. It's probably that you didn't import your components (in top of your `App.js` file). If you are just starting to learn react just create another project with `create-react-app myprojectname` in cmd. So you can focus on learning code first.